# MySQL change user login from one plugin type to another

Tags: mysql, authentication, mysql-8.0

I'm in the process of testing MySQL 8.0.

I have set up a test database, and the first thing I want to do is import my user account from MySQL 5.7.

So to do this I run:

```
/*ON MySQL 5.7*/
SHOW CREATE USER `username`@`1.2.3.4`;
```

This gives me:

```
CREATE USER 'username'@'1.2.3.4' IDENTIFIED WITH 'mysql_native_password' AS '*1BDAB0F57D8247DF5EFE4927F144138B3B7F2C6B' REQUIRE NONE PASSWORD EXPIRE DEFAULT ACCOUNT UNLOCK;
```

I run this on MySQL 8.0, and it creates a user. I check I can log in fine. However, the default in MySQL 8.0 is to use the `caching_sha2_password` plugin for authentication. So how can I upgrade my login to use the new plugin?

(n.b. this is my login, but at some point I will need to move all my colleagues logins, so assume I don't know what the pasword is).

I have looked all over the web, and found lots of docuemntation about the plugin, but none that say how to convert from one type to the other (apart from delete the user and start again, but that's no use if I don't know the password).

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing the user passwords, you can:

1. Migrate the user accounts as you have described in your question (SHOW CREATE USER)
2. Set the passwords to 'expired'
   `ALTER USER user@host PASSWORD EXPIRE;`
3. Ask the users to login and change the passwords. On an expired password, login is possible but the only action possible is to SET the password.

Comment: Sorry, it still says `plugin=mysql_native_password`. Plus, it seems a very inefficient way of migrating many user accounts to the new database, a lot of which are for applications rather than individuals.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not aware of any automated migration methods since encrypted passwords cannot be decrypted (or very hard to do if I say so). For application users, you'll have the actual text password in config files and so could write a bash script or something similar in your favourite scripting language. For other "users" they will have to reset the password to be able to use the newer caching_sha2_password that is default in MySQL8. Using the output of `SHOW CREATE USER`, you should be able to get the users across from the old MySQL ver. Once on the new server, change the `plugin` ...

Comment: cont from the above... Once on the new server, change the `plugin` column value to be `mysql_native_password ` as described in https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/account-upgrades.html Having changed the `mysql.user.plugin` column, when the password is changed by the users manually, it will be using the new plugin for encrypting the password in DB. You can force the users to change their passwords by expiring it as I described in my answer earlier. I am also in the process of migrating to MySQL 8 and faced similar challenges!

Comment: OK cheers, that seems like an oversight by Oracle, not allowing a live migration of users in that way. I raised a feature request to see what they say about it (95841).

Comment: One option that has been presented is to use `ALTER USER 'user'@'host' IDENTIFIED WITH caching_sha2_password;` Although this expires the password (not what you want if it is your busy website you are migrating).

Comment: Or if you know the password `ALTER USER 'user'@'1.2.3.4' IDENTIFIED WITH caching_sha2_password BY 'password';`. But that assumes you know everyone's password.

Comment: @IGGt how does a user change their password when they can't use their existing password (because the plugin has changed but the authentication_string has not, the auth_string is essentially random garbage)?